# How to calculate average of array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, average

So I have in this array code

```
$numers = array
(
  array(198,208,109,11,636),
  array(198,188,84,55,756),
  array(194,206,113,13,531),
  array(184,213,127,18,101),
  array(194,213,127,23,110),
  array(984,213,127,44,125),
  array(184,213,127,88,980),
  array(995,211,129,63,888)
);
```

Now I want to calculate the column average (from first 198, 198, 194, 184, 194, 984, 184, 995) from second (208, 188, 206, 213, 213, 213, 213, 211) and so on until the fifth last column.

I don't know how I can do it, so can someone explain to me how I can calculate the column average of each column.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$numers = array(
  array(198,208,109,11,636),
  array(198,188,84,55,756),
  array(194,206,113,13,531),
  array(184,213,127,18,101),
  array(194,213,127,23,110),
  array(984,213,127,44,125),
  array(184,213,127,88,980),
  array(995,211,129,63,888)
);

$num_cols = count($numers[0]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i++) {
  $column = array_column($numers, $i); 
  $average = array_sum($column) / count($column);
  echo "Column $i average: $average<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Column 0 average: 391.375
Column 1 average: 208.125
Column 2 average: 117.875
Column 3 average: 39.375
Column 4 average: 515.875
```

Comment: The line with $num_cols is no longer needed with a foreach: https://3v4l.org/B7v7Kd